How to Run/Debug Go source code on windows?
I have downloaded go sourcecode from https://github.com/golang/go/
I used vscode to open this go source-code project
but when I was running test, The error 'use of internal package internal' showing..
how to run go source code on windows so that I can debug go source-code?

Have you tried building the code? (simplest way to check is running go build); a "use of internal package" error sounds like an issue with your code.
